# Prove $\nabla f(x)\bot T_xM$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, tangent-spaces

Given $M$ manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ $C^1$ function
Prove if f is constant on $M$ then  $\nabla f(x)\bot T_xM$

Attempt:
we know that $f(x)=a$ for all $x\in M$ then we can assume that $a=0$ wlog(otherwise we can do some linear transformation) so we can see that $M=\{x|f(x)=0\}$ and we know that the tangent space at x is defined by $\{\nabla f(x)\}^{\bot}=T_xM \to T_xM\bot\nabla f(x)$ as required.

Am I right here?

Comment: The equality $M=\{x \mid f(x)=0\}$ is not correct. You can only deduce that $M \subseteq \{x \mid f(x)=0\}$

Comment: Also is $M$ a manifold or a submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$?

Comment: I was given $M\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ this question from an old exam

Comment: What is the precise text of this old exam?

Comment: It's in Hebrew so I translated it

Comment: OK. And were you **very** careful in the translation of manifold vs submanifold?

Comment: We haven't learnt submanifolds at this course :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128242/discussion-between-mathcounterexamples-net-and-convxy).